# Have 52 regular deck of cards, probability getting the first red ace?

Tags: probability

So if we have a regular deck of $52$ cards that is shuffled, then what is the probability of drawing the first red ace on the $k$-th card? And which k would maximize the probability?

I wasn't entirely sure of computing the probability. 
Here are my thoughts:

Have $52$ cards, thinking about the $k$-th card. There are two red aces, so the probability would be $\frac{2}{52-(k+1)}$?

I am entirely lost on maximizing $k$. Would anyone be able to help me out? Or guide me on maximizing $k$? Is my probability correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a well-shuffled deck, the positions of the two red aces are two randomly chosen numbers from $\{1,2,\dots, 52\}$. There are ${52\choose 2}$ such pairs of numbers.

If the first red ace is at position $k$, then the other red ace must belong to the set $\{k+1,\dots, 52\}$ and there are $52-k$ such possibilities.

Therefore the probability that the first red ace is in position $k$ is the ratio $${52-k\over {52\choose 2}},$$ which is maximized by taking $k$ as small as possible.

Comment: So would 52 choose 2 be the possible placements of red aces in the deck?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 2):

There are two red aces in the deck, diamond ace and heart ace. The probability that the first card is not red ace is $\frac{52-2}{52}$. The probability that the second one is not the red ace, given than the first one was not is $\frac{51-2}{51}$. The probability the the first $k-1$ are not red ace and the $k$-th one is thus equals:
$$
    \left(\prod_{m=1}^{k-1} \frac{52-1-m}{52-m+1}\right) \cdot \frac{2}{52-(k-1)} = \left( \frac{(52-(k-1))(52-k)}{(52-1+1)(52-2+1)}\right) \cdot \frac{2}{52-(k-1)}  = \frac{2(52-k)}{52 (52-1)}
$$
Thus the probability is maximal for $k=1$.

Comment: What does the (52-1-m)/(52-m+1) stand for? I understand that the second part would be the probability for the two red aces. Also, how did you find that the maximal is k=1? And thank you for your help!!

Comment: It stands for the probability of not drawing a red ace at $m$-th step, given that no red ace had been drawn on prior steps.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting the same answer:

Consider a row of 52 empty slots, and put the **ordered** cards in randomly selected slots.  The first two cards to be placed are the two red aces (why not?).  The chances of the first red ace going in the k-th slot out of the 52 empty ones is $\frac{1}{52}$, and after that the chance of the second going in any slot **after** that, out of the 51 remaining, is $\frac{52-k}{51}$

Or, the first red ace could go in any of the "after" positions, probability  $\frac{52-k}{52}$, and the second red ace could go in the k-th slot out of the 51 remaining, with probability $\frac{1}{51}$.

Multiplying out and adding the two results gives the same answer as above.